# PHP XMLReader read , edit Node , write XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, data-manipulation

I have an XML file which is very very large (millions of records). Due to speed and memory constraints I plan to use `XMLReader`/`XMLWriter`.

I need to read the file, getting one record, change its attribute, and finally save XML again.

For testing I created an XML file and write some records into it using these lines:

```
$doc = new XMLWriter();  
$doc->openURI($xmlFile);  
$doc->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');  
$doc->setIndent(4);   
$doc->startElement('DBOS'); 
for($r=0;$r<10; $r++){
    $doc->startElement('ITEMS');
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++){
        $doc->startElement('ITEM');  
        $doc->writeAttribute('id', $r.'-'.$i);
        $doc->endElement();
    }
    $doc->endElement();
}
$doc->endElement();  
$doc->endDocument();   
$doc->flush();
```

I read it again using this:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open($xmlFile)){
    die("Failed to open 'data.xml'");
}
while($reader->read()){
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'ITEMS') {
        $node = $reader->expand();
        $items = $node->childNodes;
        foreach ($items as $ik => $itm ){
            print $itm->textContent.'<br/>';
            // how to change the ID Attribute of a Node (DomNode) and save changes to the original XML File 
        }
        break;
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

**My question**: How to change the `id` attribute of a `DomNode` and save changes to the original XML File **using XMLWriter** again?

Answer (score 5):

> How to change the id attribute of a DomNode and save changes to the original XML File using XMLWriter again?

This does not work that way. If you use [XMLReader](http://php.net/class.xmlreader) and [XMLWriter](http://php.net/class.xmlwriter) to operate on the *same* file simultaneously, the file will be truncated by the writer and the reader will spit errors and stop working.

However, you can operate on *different* files.

So what you can do is to use an **XMLReader** to read the document and while you operate on it use **XMLWriter** to write to another document based on what you've read and occasionally modified. After you're done, you can then rename the newly written file to the old filename.

### Example

For an XML document (shortened for the example, **XMLReader** and **XMLWriter** make naturally sense with really huge documents) like this one modeled a bit after your question:

```
<DBOS>
    <ITEMS>
        <ITEM>item #1</ITEM>
        <ITEM>item #2</ITEM>
        <ITEM>item #3</ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
    <ITEMS>
        <ITEM>item #4</ITEM>
        <ITEM>item #5</ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
</DBOS>
```

A working code-example is:

```
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of the XMLReaderIterator package.
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2012, 2014 hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com>
 *
 * Example: Write XML with XMLWriter while reading from XMLReader with XMLWriterIteration
 */

require('xmlreader-iterators.php'); // require XMLReaderIterator library

$xmlInputFile  = 'data/dobs-items.xml';
$xmlOutputFile = 'php://output';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlInputFile);

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri($xmlOutputFile);

$iterator = new XMLWritingIteration($writer, $reader);

$writer->startDocument();

$itemsCount = 0;
$itemCount  = 0;
foreach ($iterator as $node) {
    $isElement = $node->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT;


    if ($isElement && $node->name === 'ITEMS') {
        // increase counter for <ITEMS> elements and reset <ITEM> counter
        $itemsCount++;
        $itemCount = 0;
    }

    if ($isElement && $node->name === 'ITEM') {
        // increase <ITEM> counter and insert "id" attribute
        $itemCount++;
        $writer->startElement($node->name);
        $writer->writeAttribute('id', $itemsCount . "-" . $itemCount);
        if ($node->isEmptyElement) {
            $writer->endElement();
        }
    } else {
        // handle everything else
        $iterator->write();
    }
}

$writer->endDocument();
```

The output then is (exemplary to standard output, any valid PHP file-name can be used):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DBOS>
    <ITEMS>
        <ITEM id="1-1">item #1</ITEM>
        <ITEM id="1-2">item #2</ITEM>
        <ITEM id="1-3">item #3</ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
    <ITEMS>
        <ITEM id="2-1">item #4</ITEM>
        <ITEM id="2-2">item #5</ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
</DBOS>
```

As this example shows, the id attributes are added based on the numbering by the different counter variables.

The **XMLWritingIteration** makes this easy as it deals with all other nodes and cases thanks to `$iterator->write()`.

The example and code is part of [the XMLReaderIterator package](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator). There is also another example that is creating a **DOMDocument** based on **XMLReader**, it is part of [an answer to *"How to distinguish between empty element and null-size string in DOMDocument?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109776/367456).